# Why do we use return in promise chain even we already have return in the function?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm new to JavaScript. In the following code, may I know why I still have to use return getRecipe(IDs[2]) instead of just call  getRecipe(IDs[2]) in the .then method? Even getRecipe() already have return new Promise inside it? I find that I'll get an undefined error if I don't use return in the .then method. Is the return actually return the promise we get to the next then? But why and how? Thank you so much!

```
const getIDs = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve([523, 883, 432, 974]);
  }, 1500);
});

const getRecipe = recID => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(
      ID => {
        const recipe = { title: 'Fresh tomato pasta', publisher: 'Jonas' };
        resolve(`${ID} : ${recipe.title}`);
      },
      1500,
      recID
    );
  });
};

getIDs
  .then(IDs => {
    console.log(IDs);
    return getRecipe(IDs[2]);
  })
  .then(recipe => {
    console.log(recipe);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error!!');
  });
```

Comment: You need to return the function, which returns a Promise so you can chain it with .then().

Comment: `IDs => { ....}` is a function ... with no return statement, you don't return anything (i.e. you return undefined) - there's no difference inside a `.then` callback as with any function

Comment: The information under *Return value* should answer your question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Thank you so much! But I'm so confused that  we already have this "return new Promise((resolve, reject)", this return inside the getRecipe, why we still need another return outside this getRecipe(IDs[2])?

Comment: You are dealing with two functions @Ying. `getRecipe`, and also the anonymous function that you pass to `then()`. That anonymous function needs to return the value returned by `getRecipe`.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Mark Meyer Could you please make it more detailed? What is the anonymous function like and what're the things we get with and without the returns? Thank you so much for your help....I'm super confused with this

Comment: Thank you so much! @Bravo ~ So return is actually the return for the IDs function right? So are we returning the result of the getRecipe promise or the promise itself so we can keep using then method for it? If it's the promise itself why we have the result of getRecipe(IDs[2])? If it's the result why we can keep using .then method? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In a chain of .then statements, when you return something from a .then, it goes to the next .then, if there is one. In this case, we are using .then statements to do multiple tasks, and the first task is to get a recipe according to some ID. Once this recipe is received (as a result of the getRecipe function) we return it into the next .then, which has the task of console.log'ing the recipe. If we did not return the getRecipe(ID[2]) result, we would have no 'recipe' parameter of the next .then statement

Comment: Thank you so much! So " when you return something from a .then, it goes to the next .then" is the rule of promise chain right? And "getRecipe(IDs[2])" actually become the recipe parameter in the next then right? And when we use return getRecipe(IDs[2]), this getRecipe(IDs[2]) is actually the promise itself with the id of 432 
 new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(
      ID => {
        const recipe = { title: 'Fresh tomato pasta', publisher: 'Jonas' };
        ......
    );
  });
right? Is' not run or a result of this promise right? Thank you so much!

Comment: Ah.. Is the content of the resolve of getRecipe(IDs[2])  actually become the recipe parameter of the next .then? But the whole promise is returned to the next .then?